# Attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID when building IOS ipa for codenameone Charts

Tags: codenameone, achartengine, ipa

The CODENAME ONE BUILD SERVER is throwing the above IOS build error when I try to build an ipa from https://github.com/codenameone/Charts .

The simulator runs correctly and even the android apk are compiled without any build error.

Similar issue has already been reported and fixed here => https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/codenameone-discussions/N-N6eU9y7sk/cnDY2jQFBAAJ  .

I have to chunk the logs because the post form is limited to 30 000 characters  :

```
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/TreeMap$SubMapValuesCollection.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/TreeMap$TreeMapEntry.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/TreeMap$UnboundedEntryIterator.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/TreeMap$UnboundedKeyIterator.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/TreeMap$UnboundedValueIterator.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/TreeMap.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/TreeSet.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/Vector$1.class
Parsing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/classes/java/util/Vector.class
outputDirectory is: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/dist/ChartsDemo-src
Rewrite /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/dist/ChartsDemo.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata with 1 changes
Rewrite /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/dist/ChartsDemo.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj with 58 changes
Rewrite /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/dist/ChartsDemo-src/ChartsDemo-Info.plist with 5 changes
Executing: echo chmod 0755 /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb chmod 0755 /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb
Executing: chmod 0755 /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb Executing: echo /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb
Executing: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb `<PBXGroup name=`Frameworks` UUID=`0F634E7718E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA218E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXGroup name=`Products` UUID=`0F634E7618E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXNativeTarget name=`ChartsDemoTests` UUID=`0F634EA018E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `product_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA318E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA418E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9F18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EAD18E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
Error during processing: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
Backtrace:
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:89:in `construct_buildable_name'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:59:in `set_reference_target'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:16:in `block in initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/xml_element_wrapper.rb:53:in `create_xml_element_with_fallback'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:14:in `initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:96:in `new'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:96:in `block in initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/xml_element_wrapper.rb:53:in `create_xml_element_with_fallback'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:77:in `initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb:186:in `new'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb:186:in `add_build_target'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:756:in `block in recreate_user_schemes'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:754:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:754:in `recreate_user_schemes'
    /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build6171032898102630775xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb:5:in `<main>'
An error occurred recreating schemes, but the build still might work...
Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod init 
[!] `<PBXGroup name=`Frameworks` UUID=`0F634E7718E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA218E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXGroup name=`Products` UUID=`0F634E7618E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXNativeTarget name=`ChartsDemoTests` UUID=`0F634EA018E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `product_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA318E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA418E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9F18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EAD18E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod install Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `ChartsDemo.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.

[!] `<PBXGroup name=`Frameworks` UUID=`0F634E7718E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA218E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXGroup name=`Products` UUID=`0F634E7618E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXNativeTarget name=`ChartsDemoTests` UUID=`0F634EA018E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `product_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA318E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA418E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9F18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EAD18E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
openssl pkcs12 -in [password redacted] -out cert.crt.pem -password pass:passwordHidden -passout pass:password
Mac verify error: invalid password?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in [password redacted] -out cert.crt.pem -password pass:passwordHidden -passout pass:password

Mac verify error: invalid password?
```

It looks like your P12 certificate is invalid, I'm guessing you didn't use the certificate wizard to generate a proper P12 certificate.